# Updating CORS Policy Origins During RunTime on All Servers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to update the CORS Policy Origins during runtime. However, It is only updating on one server and not on all the servers. My web application is hosted on 4 servers and I want to update it on all 4 servers.

Here is the Startup.cs Code:

```
 // Configure CORS
            services.AddCors(c =>
            {
                c.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", options => options
                .SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains()
                .WithOrigins(origins)
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials()
                );
            });
```

Code To Update the Origins During runtime :

```
public class CorsPolicyAccessor : ICorsPolicyAccessor
    {
        private readonly ICorsPolicyProvider _cors;
        private readonly string _corsPolicy;

        public CorsPolicyAccessor(ICorsPolicyProvider cors)
        {
            _corsPolicy = "CorsPolicy";
            _cors = cors;
        }

        public async Task<CorsPolicy> GetPolicy(HttpContext context)
        {
            return await _cors.GetPolicyAsync(context,_corsPolicy);
        }

        public async Task AddDomainToPolicy(string origin, HttpContext context)
        {
            //_cors.GetPolicyAsync(context, _corsPolicy);
            (await _cors.GetPolicyAsync(context, _corsPolicy)).Origins.Add(origin);
        }
```

I have tried searching a lot and have tried corsoptions as wel. But No Luck yet.

Comment: Not sure why the [tag:cors] is used, since your problem seems to be a due to a deployment problem more that a problem about CORS specifically.

Comment: @jub0bs any idea, what could be wrong with the deployment?